# Python: Cerberus coerce field when not empty

Tags: python, cerberus, coerce

I would like to allow a field to be empty, but when it is not empty I want it to be Integer and range checked.
I will need to coerce the field, when not empty, to int because it comes in as string.
Is there a way to do this?
My approach is below but that does not appear to work.
I have done a bunch of research but have yet to see how to do this in what I have found.

Sample:

```
from cerberus import Validator

v = Validator()
v.schema = {
    'name': { 'type': 'string', 'minlength': 2},
    'age': {
        'oneof': [
            {'type': 'string', 'empty': True},
            {'type': 'integer', 'min': 5, 'max': 130, 'coerce': int, 'empty': False},
        ]
    }
}

if v.validate({'name': 'John', 'age': ''}):
    print('valid data')
else:
    print('invalid data')
    print(v.errors)
```

I get an error in validator creation:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ken\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\cerberus\validator.py", line 562, in schema
    self._schema = DefinitionSchema(self, schema)
  File "C:\Users\ken\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\cerberus\schema.py", line 82, in __init__
    self.validate(schema)
  File "C:\Users\ken\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\cerberus\schema.py", line 262, in validate
    self._validate(schema)
  File "C:\Users\ken\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\cerberus\schema.py", line 278, in _validate
    raise SchemaError(self.schema_validator.errors)
cerberus.schema.SchemaError: {'age': [{'oneof': [{'coerce': ['unknown rule']}]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment, and I know this isn't a good answer but I'm not sure where else to put this.

The reason you are getting that error is because `coerce` isn't a valid rule within the context of a `oneof` rule. According to the [docs](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html?highlight=oneof#of-rules), `coerce` is considered a normalization rule and those aren't allowed within any of the `*of` rules.

I know it's not a good solution, but you can use the [check_with](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html?highlight=oneof#check-with) rule and write a custom validation function. Then in that function, you can simply dump all the check logic you have in there. Something like this:

```
def validate_age(f, v, e):
    # Perform your checks

my_schema = {
    "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "minlength": 2
    },
    "age": {
        "check_with": validate_age
    }
}
```

Comment: Great suggestion - thanks  - and that was the hack i implemented, but I was looking for a more generic way to do this so that I was not creating these "check_with" functions - but could configure the solution to accept inputs that are in general string when they come in but when populated reflect a different "type" be it int/float/date.... and when not empty leverage coerce to perform this and then perform the check.  Based on what you documented - that does not appear to be how coerce works - so I will have to think of a way to do this in a more generic sense.